# Workaround for Python partial determining parameters upon definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

I have been working on a card-based combat game to practice Python coding, and I have objects for the players and the cards. I have been using functools.partial to assign an ability to each card object when I create it, and that has been working so far like this:

```
from functools import partial

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
    def play_card(self, card):
        card.ability(player=self)

human = Player()
computer = Player()
human.opponent = computer
computer.opponent = human

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, ability):
        self.ability = ability

def attack(amount, player):
    player.opponent.health -= amount

working_card = Card(partial(attack, 8))
human.play_card(working_card)
```

This is obviously a vastly simplified version of the code, but it's the important part. When I call human.play_card(working_card), the human Player object executes the function play_card(card=working_card), which then activates the working_card.ability() partial function, initiating the attack(amount=8, player=human) function.

But then I introduce a variable as one of the parameters of the partial function like this:

```
broken_card = Card(partial(attack, player.health))
human.play_card(broken_card)
```

The partial function is trying to determine the value of player.health when the Card object is first created, when it does not know what 'player' is. I want it instead to determine the value of player.health when attack(amount, player) is called, which is when 'player' has meaning. I have tried using lambda and placing the attack() function inside the Card object with no success, and I could not find any answers to this sort of question on the Internet. I need some way to work around partial trying to determine player.health when it is first called, if not explicitly than by a restructuring of the way my code's logic works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lambda` instead of `partial` to defer the evaluation of parameters:

```
broken_card = Card(lambda *args, **kwargs: attack(player.health, *args, **kwargs))
```

Keep in mind that `player` has to be available in the same scope as where this `lambda` is defined. however. Since `player` happens to be the second parameter of `attack`, you can make `lambda` make use of the known parameter:

```
broken_card = Card(lambda player: attack(player.health, player))
```